# understanding pytorch quantization model output

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

Here's two ways to use pytorch's `mobilenet_v3_large`.

The first **not** using quantization:

```py
import torchvision
import torch

model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
x = [torch.rand(3, 300, 400), torch.rand(3, 500, 400)]
predictions = model(x)
print(predictions)
```

gives an output:

```
[{'boxes': tensor([], size=(0, 4), grad_fn=<StackBackward0>), 'labels': tensor([], dtype=torch.int64), 'scores': tensor([], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>)}, {'boxes': tensor([], size=(0, 4), grad_fn=<StackBackward0>), 'labels': tensor([], dtype=torch.int64), 'scores': tensor([], grad_fn=<IndexBackward0>)}]
```

The second **does** use quantization:

```py
import torch
from torchvision.io import read_image
from torchvision.models.quantization import mobilenet_v3_large, MobileNet_V3_Large_QuantizedWeights

torch.backends.quantized.engine = 'qnnpack'
img = read_image("someimage.jpg")
# Step 1: Initialize model with the best available weights
weights = MobileNet_V3_Large_QuantizedWeights.DEFAULT
model = mobilenet_v3_large(weights=weights, quantize=True)
model.eval()
# Step 2: Initialize the inference transforms
preprocess = weights.transforms()
# Step 3: Apply inference preprocessing transforms
batch = preprocess(img).unsqueeze(0)
# Step 4: Use the model and print the predicted category
prediction = model(batch)
print(prediction)
```

which when run, outputs something like this:

```
tensor([[-12.1885,  -6.0943,  -2.9548,  -4.6169,  -6.4636,  -4.0628,  -8.8644,
          -7.7563,  -6.8330,  -6.0943,  -6.2789,  -5.9096,...]])
```

I'm trying to figure out how to reconcile these two outputs. How can I retrieve "boxes", "labels" etc. from the quantized model?

Thanks!

torch version = 1.12.0

torchvision version = 0.13.0

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the wrong module/weights. If you want to perform object detection, you have to import your models from the `torchvision.models.detection` module.

In your second code snippet, you are loading weights of only MobileNet network and using it on a MobileNet network, not an object detection network (the two are different). The output you got was basically the features/representation of your input image.

In your first code snippet, you used `fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn`, which uses ResNet50 as its backbone network and not MobileNet. You cannot use MobileNet weights with a ResNet backbone network. The following code will work because the backbone network is ResNet50 and the weights are also of a ResNet50 network.

[Related PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn.html#torchvision.models.detection.FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights)

```py
import torch
from torchvision.io import read_image
from torchvision.models.quantization import ResNet50_QuantizedWeights

model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=ResNet50_QuantizedWeights)
model.eval()
x = [torch.rand(3, 300, 400), torch.rand(3, 500, 400)]
predictions = model(x)
print(predictions)
```